# How to fetch image from sqlite database and display it second page in list view in android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-sqlite

I am having a lot of trouble displaying images from the database.
The image is being stored in the SQLite database but it is not displayed in the list view of the second page.
Many methods have been adopted, but are not working.

my code here
activity_registration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Registration">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:id="@+id/avatarid"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtfname"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="text" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="submit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Edit"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_display"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="display"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Registration.java

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText efname;
    Button submit,display,edit;
    DBmain dbmainobj;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int id=0;

    private ImageView avatar;

    public static final int Gallerypic=1;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST=100;
    public static final int STORAGE_REQUEST=200;
    public static final int IMAGE_PICKCAMERA_REOUEST=300;
    public static final int IMAGE_PICKGALLERY_REQUEST=400;
    String cameraPermission[];
    String storagePermission[];
    Uri imageuri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_registration );
        findid();
        dbmainobj=new DBmain( Registration.this );
        getdata ();
        clear();
       editdata();
       avatar=findViewById ( R.id.avatarid );
       avatar.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               showImagePicDialog ();
           }
       } );

    }
    private void showImagePicDialog() {
        String options[] = {"Camera", "Gallery"};
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                } else if (which == 1) {
                    if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void editdata() {

        if(getIntent().getBundleExtra( "userdata" )!=null)
        {
            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getBundleExtra( "userdata" );
            id=bundle.getInt( "id" );

            efname.setText( bundle.getString( "fname" ));

            edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void clear() {

        efname.setText( "" );

    }

    private void getdata() {

        submit.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(  );
                cv.put( "fname" ,efname.getText().toString());
                cv.put ("avatar",imageViewToByte(avatar) );

                db=dbmainobj.getWritableDatabase();
                Long recid=db.insert( "student",null,cv );
                if(recid!=null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText( Registration.this, "Data Insert Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText( Registration.this, "Data Not Insert Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }


            }
        } );

        display.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity( new Intent( Registration.this,Displaydata.class ) );
            }
        } );

        edit.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues(  );
                cv.put( "fname" ,efname.getText().toString());
                cv.put ( "avatar",Registration.imageViewToByte ( avatar ) );

                db=dbmainobj.getWritableDatabase();
                long recid = db.update("student",cv,"id="+id,null);
                if(recid!=-1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText( Registration.this, "Data Update Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    submit.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                    edit.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                    clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText( Registration.this, "Data Not Update Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }


            }
        } );


    }

    private void findid() {

        efname=findViewById( R.id.edtfname );

        submit=findViewById( R.id.btn_submit );
        display=findViewById( R.id.btn_display );
        edit=findViewById( R.id.btn_edit);
    }

    private Boolean checkStoragePermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        requestPermissions(storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    private Boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        requestPermissions(cameraPermission, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean camera_accepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageaccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (camera_accepted && writeStorageaccepted) {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable Camera and Storage Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean writeStorageaccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (writeStorageaccepted) {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable Storage Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void pickFromGallery() {
        CropImage.activity().start(Registration.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                Picasso.with(this).load(resultUri).into(avatar);
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView avatar) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)avatar.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

activity_displaydata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#83C9C7"
    tools:context=".Displaydata">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Displaydata.java

```
public class Displaydata extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBmain dbmainobj;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ListView lv;
    String[] sfname;
    int[] id;
    byte[] avatar;
    ImageView savatar;
    private Bitmap bitmapImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_displaydata );
        findid ();
        dbmainobj = new DBmain ( Displaydata.this );
        dis ();
    }
    private void dis() {
        db = dbmainobj.getReadableDatabase ();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ( "select * from student", null );
        if (cursor.getCount () > 0) {
            id = new int[cursor.getCount ()];
            sfname = new String[cursor.getCount ()];
            byte[] savatar = new byte[cursor.getCount ()];

            int i = 0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext ()) {
                id[i] = cursor.getInt ( 0 );
                sfname[i] = cursor.getString ( 1 );
            //    byte[] avatar = cursor.getBlob ( 2 );
                avatar = cursor.getBlob(2);
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray ( avatar, 0, avatar.length );


                i++;
            }
            Custom adapter = new Custom ();
            lv.setAdapter ( adapter );
        }
    }
    private void findid() {
        lv = findViewById ( R.id.lv );
    }


    private class Custom extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sfname.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView txtfname;
            Button edit, delete;
            ImageView imageobj;
            v = LayoutInflater.from ( Displaydata.this ).inflate ( R.layout.singledata, viewGroup, false );
            txtfname = v.findViewById ( R.id.txt_fname );
            imageobj = v.findViewById ( R.id.imageview );

            edit = v.findViewById ( R.id.btn_edit );
            delete = v.findViewById ( R.id.btn_delete );
            txtfname.setText ( sfname[position] );

            imageobj.setImageBitmap ( bitmapImage );
            edit.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle ();
                    data.putInt ( "id", id[position] );
                    data.putString ( "fname", sfname[position] );
                    data.getByte ( "avatar", avatar[position] );
                    Intent i = new Intent ( Displaydata.this, Registration.class );
                    i.putExtra ( "userdata", data );
                    startActivity ( i );
                }
            } );
            delete.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    db = dbmainobj.getReadableDatabase ();
                    long recdelete = db.delete ( "student", "id=" + id[position], null );
                    if (recdelete != -1) {
                        Toast.makeText ( Displaydata.this, "Record Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                        dis ();
                    }
                }
            } );
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

singledata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_fname"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="139dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_edit"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

database file
DBmain.java

```
public class DBmain extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String sql;
    public DBmain(@Nullable Context context) {
        super( context, "studentdb", null, 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        sql="create table student(id integer primary key,fname text,avatar blob)";
        db.execSQL( sql );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        sql="drop table student";
        db.execSQL( sql );
        onCreate( db );

    }
}
```

crop image dependencies

```
    // This library is used for crop image feature

    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

// This library is used for loading the

// cropped image into ImageView.


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Tag #java and #sql as well

Comment: what is your problem? you are not getting image from database?